# NAT Hole Punching in boost::asio

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio, nat

I'm trying to implement NAT hole punching with boost::asio. By my understanding, NAT hole punch works like this (UDP/TCP):

1. Client A binds to a port and connects to Server S, and Client B does the same.
2. When S receives both request and matched, it sends the ip and port of A to B, and B to A.
3. A and B receives each other's ip and port, and now they send a message to each other from the same port and form a connection (because they are expecting a reply?)

So in boost::asio, I was able to achieve step 1-2, but however because both the client is not port-forwarded, if I attempt to connect from one client to the other, it just give me error like "client actively refuse connection" or "No response from client" (surprisingly the 2 clients have different error even tho they are using the same function).

And it seems like I can't run any `asio::async_write` without a successful `async_connect` or `asio::tcp::socket::connect`. And of course, both of these connect function gives me error when the destination port is not forwarded.

So how can I implement NAT hole punching in this situation, am I missing something in boost::asio? Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, I've edited some more info on what functions i was using. May I know what is not clear in the question for you? thanks!

Comment: Sam, the question its self is pretty good man, what I meant is if you have some code to share is more suitable for Stack Overflow Guidelines. Unfortunately I'm not able to answer your question as I am not a C++ developer, but I know Stack Overflow and how it works pretty well. You should give always some of your source code, so that user expert in the area (C++ in this case) can better help you, Not only you will get a quicker answer, but Also more quality answer and avoid to get downvote and even close the question if is not clear enough. Is just an advice

Comment: WP: [as a result of the connections using valid port numbers, restrictive firewalls or routers accept and forward the incoming packets on each side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) - it would appear that the router(s)/firewalls are not cooperating to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "*client actively refuse connection*" error I assume you're trying a TCP connection. There is fundamental difference in how UDP and TCP hole punching works.

> 3. A and B receives each other's ip and port, and now they send a message to each other from the same port and form a connection (because they are expecting a reply?)

This is NOT how TCP hole punching works. Since TCP is point-to-point, in step 3 you have to *predict* the next incoming port of either A or B, and A or B need to try to establish a new connection using the predicted port of the other side. Obviously there are many different NAT implementations, and it is not always possible to reliably predict the port allocation, especially in case of carrier-grade NAT. Refer to [TCP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) for further details. As an alternative to TCP hole punching, have a look into [UPnP](https://www.google.com/search?q=programmatically%20open%20port%20forwarding%20using%20upnp) to add a port forwarding.

Comment: I see, thanks for correcting me, was I describing UDP hole punching instead? However, regarding predicting the port of the other client, I was able to verify that both of the client is sending out connection from the same port as the ones they were using for server S, so the server S is indeed passing the correct port number, so it seems like no prediction is needed. I am aware that it `requires the use of the SO_REUSEADDR on the TCP sockets` , so I've also make sure that is on as well. However, I'll give UDP a try first for now. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: As for UPnP, I've already had it as backup plan, but unfortunately, the major ISP in my country has disabled UPnP on their user's modem by default (IKR), so I can't rely on that. Same goes with NAT PMP. But thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Yes, you described UDP hole punching. If your NAT is using the port preservation allocation scheme, then you can simply allocate a new port and communicate it via the server (or UDP) to the other side. Then proceed with TCP connection establishment as described in [TCP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching#Details_of_a_typical_TCP_connection_instantiation_with_TCP_Hole_Punching).